# Hi just a newbie ruby programmer here wanting to understand a few things

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to see if each position on a board is taken by this line of code. Can someone explain to me why this works?

```
def full?(board)
  **board.all?{|position| position == "X" || position == "O"}
end**
```

And to see who is the winner, can someone explain to me the mechanics of the lines with the stars.

```
def winner(board)
  ****if winning_combo == won?(board)
    board[winning_combo.first]****
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell exactly what the structure of `board` is from the example you provided but it seems to be some `Enumerable`.

Take a look at [Enumerable.all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

> all? [{ |obj| block } ] → true or false
>
> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil.

So `board.all?{|position| position == "X" || position == "O"}` tests each element of `board` to see if it is either `"X"` or `"O"` and `full?` will return false if any `position` has not yet been set to one of those values.

We have no way to know what `winning_combo` is from the code provided or exactly what the `won?` function does. `winning_combo.first` might return an index, in that case if `board` is an `Array` then  `board[winning_combo.first]` would get one element of the board. That seems reasonable in this case since from `full?` we see that the elements are `"X"` or `"O"` so `winner` would then return one of those characters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!